# Move an item from a list and remove it from the previous one in the same for each

Tags: vb.net

Sorry, I have three linked lists in a form1 and three in a form2 (with the same name)  and i want to pass specific selected linked items on the linked lists of the form1 to the linked lists of the form 2.

```
    For Each lists In {frm2.lst1, frm2.lst2, frm2.lst3}
            lists.Items.Add(DirectCast(Controls(lists.Name), ListBox).SelectedItem) 
    'this is supposed to add the linked items on the form1 (DirectCast(Controls(lists.Name), ListBox).SelectedItem) to the linked lists on form2
                DirectCast(Controls(lists.Name), ListBox).Items.RemoveAt(DirectCast(Controls(lists.Name), ListBox).SelectedIndex)
'this is supposed to removes the selected linked items on the form1 
            Next
```

If i do this, it works:

```
Dim a = lst1.selectedindex
    For Each lists In {frm2.lst1, frm2.lst2, frm2.lst3}
     lists.Items.Add(DirectCast(Controls(lists.Name), ListBox).SelectedItem) 
    Next
    For Each lists In {frm2.lst1, frm2.lst2, frm2.lst3}
    DirectCast(Controls(lists.Name), ListBox).Items.RemoveAt(a)
    Next
```

But I want to know how make it in the same for each

Comment: You might build a For ... Next to loop through the forms, each of these loops running through the same procedure you already have but on a different form.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a fair simpler soution to have all these list boxes bound to the same collections?

Comment: You may want to look at the .net LinkedList(Of T) class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netcore-3.1#:~:text=NET%20Framework.,are%20O(1)%20operations.&text=Each%20node%20in%20a%20LinkedList,backward%20to%20the%20Previous%20node.

Comment: Do you get any error? What is not working?

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to do this, IMHO:

Make a new form, drop 4 listboxes on it (named listbox1, 2, 3, and 4) and paste this code in:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim d As New DataTable
    d.Columns.Add("ShowText")
    d.Columns.Add("WhichList", GetType(Integer))

    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB1", 1)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB1 too", 1)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB1 also", 1)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB2", 2)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB2 too", 2)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB2 also", 2)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB3", 3)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB3 too", 3)
    d.Rows.Add("I started in LB3 also", 3)


    ListBox1.DataSource = New DataView(d) With {.RowFilter = "[WhichList] = 1"}
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ShowText"
    ListBox2.DataSource = New DataView(d) With {.RowFilter = "[WhichList] = 2"}
    ListBox2.DisplayMember = "ShowText"
    ListBox3.DataSource = New DataView(d) With {.RowFilter = "[WhichList] = 3"}
    ListBox3.DisplayMember = "ShowText"
    ListBox4.DataSource = New DataView(d) With {.RowFilter = "[WhichList] = 4"}
    ListBox4.DisplayMember = "ShowText"
End Sub



Private Sub ListBoxX_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick, ListBox2.DoubleClick, ListBox3.DoubleClick
    DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ListBox).SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row("WhichList") = 4
End Sub
```

Run the program and double click various items in various listboxes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach by Caius Jard.  For two forms, you'd have to make that DataTable accessible to both forms.  Then you'd use the "WhichList" column to track whether the data should appear in frm1 or frm2.  You could use another column to track which list each item belonged to as well.  It'd definitely work.

In lieu of that, however, here is how to move all selected items using a similar approach to what you already have:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' MOVE all selected items from lst1, lst2 and lst3 in frm1 to the same named controls in frm2:
    Dim ListBoxes() As ListBox = {lst1, lst2, lst3}
    For Each lb As ListBox In ListBoxes
        ' Get a reference to the control in frm2:
        Dim lbOther As ListBox = frm2.Controls.Find(lb.Name, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(lbOther) Then
            ' Make a list from all the selected indices in each ListBox
            Dim indices As New List(Of Integer)(lb.SelectedIndices.Cast(Of Integer))
            ' Add those items to frm2
            For Each i As Integer In indices
                lbOther.Items.Add(lb.Items(i))
            Next
            ' Reverse the list so we can delete the indices without messing things up:
            indices.Reverse()
            For Each i As Integer In indices
                lb.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```